# Вывести все числа из диапазона введённого с клавиатуры, в которых нет ни одной 9

Tags: java, циклы

Сама задача : Из диапазона [m, n] (включая границы)  вывести на экран те числа, в составе которых нет ни одной цифры 9.
Например: m=87, n=90
Вывод на экран: 87 88

Написать желательно циклами .

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise_2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите начало диапазона m");
        int m = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Введите окончание диапазона n");
        int n = scan.nextInt();

        int numZ = 0;

        if (n <= m) System.out.println("Неверный диапазон");
        else {
            for (int x = m; x <= n; x++) { // Прошёлся по диапазону 
                int numX = x;
                while (numX != 0) {    // Разделил на числа цифру 
                    numZ = numX % 10;
                    numX /= 10;
                    if (numZ != 9 ) // сравнил 
                        System.out.println(numZ); // Проверка кода
                                                  // Далее код не смог додумать





                }



            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Теперь вы должны написать в чём проблема и в чём собственно вопрос

Comment: Вопрос в том как решить задачу , так как проблема в том что код написанный мною выводит цифры по одной ( например не 10 , а 0 1 и тд , а если ввести 19 , то выведет только единицу , а мне нужно чтобы код выводил так : 16 17 18 ( 19 - не вводит совсем )

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Введите начало диапазона m: ");
        int m = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Введите окончание диапазона n: ");
        int n = scan.nextInt();

        int numZ = 0;

        if (n <= m) System.out.println("Неверный диапазон");
        else {
            for (int x = m; x <= n; x++) { // Прошёлся по диапазону
                int numX = x;
                boolean contains9 = false;
                while (numX != 0) {
                    if (numX % 10 == 9) { // сравнил
                        contains9 = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    numX /= 10;
                }
                if (!contains9) System.out.println(x);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
Введите начало диапазона m: 87
Введите окончание диапазона n: 90
87
88
```

С помощью преобразования числа в строку можно сократить код (цикл) до:

```
for (int x = m; x <= n; x++) { // Прошёлся по диапазону
    if (!Integer.toString(x).contains("9")) System.out.println(x);
}
```